# PEAR installation error: dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: php, macos, pear

I am trying to install PEAR on OS X Yosemite (10.10).

I changed to `/usr/lib/php` and executed `sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar` as shown [here](http://akrabat.com/computing/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-mavericks/).

Another way I tried was going to `/usr/local` and executing `curl -O  http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`and `sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar`as shown [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-pear-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx10-810-7/).

However, in each case I get the error message

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.52.1.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
Reason: image not found
```

How can I get this working? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: are you installing pear from source?

Comment: I downloaded the `go-pear.phar` file and wanted to start installation with the `php go-pear.phar`command.

Comment: I clean installed the OS and now the error is gone. Didn't find a better solution..

Answer (score 0):

you can either install pear this way

```
curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
sudo php go-pear.phar
```

if you have a mac, I would recommend that you use mac ports

```
port install pear-PEAR
```

Comment: The first way is the one I tried, and which gave me the error. I am using homebrew as well. Using both, macports and homebrew, at the same time would possibly lead to conflicts, wouldn't it?

Comment: theoretically it would create a conflict because they are both trying to write to the same place.